# How to replace the string value in extension method for lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, lambda

I would like to replace "PKMvrMedsProductIssuesId" for something like `x=>x.PKMvrMedsProductIssueId` or anything that is not based on a string. Why? Because if the database people choose to rename the field my program would crash.

```
public static SelectList MvrMedsProductErrors(this SelectList Object)
{
    MedicalVarianceEntities LinqEntitiesCtx = new MedicalVarianceEntities();
    var ProductErrorsListBoxRaw =
    (
        from x in LinqEntitiesCtx.ViewLookUpProductIssuesErrorsNames
        select x
    );

    Object = new SelectList(ProductErrorsListBoxRaw, "PKMvrMedsProductIssuesId", "MvrMedsProductIssuesErrorsNames");

    return Object;
}
```

Comment: You should handle this in you entity that is connection to the database.

Comment: what does that mean? Any articles tips keywords of how to handle that in my entity?

Comment: In pleace where you do you data access you should be able to modify the definition of the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a `SelectList`.  In order to call that constructor, you must have a string.  Any change we could propose will still result in a string (from somewhere) being passed into that constructor.

The good news is: that string can come from anywhere.  It can come from config, from the database... where ever you like.

Comment: Well is coming from an entity definition edmx.file

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact context here (what exactly "PKMvrMedsProductIssuesId" is) , but you can for example use such helper method:

```
public static string GetPropertyAsString<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    return GetPropertyInfo(expression).Name;
}
```

To use an expression to get string:

```
GetPropertyAsString<MyType>(x => x.MyTypeProperty);
```

('MyTypeProperty' is your 'PKMvrMedsProductIssuesId' any 'MyType' one of your types where you may have your property defined)

Comment: PkMvrMedsProductIssuesId is a field in the database. In order works the name of the column of a table in a database.